# UserControl renders with no width in designer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a UWP `UserControl` that contains a path element, the `Data` property of the path is bound to a string property of the `UserControl` called `Icon`. When I add my control to a page and set it's `Icon` property to a resource item, the control doesn't render the icon and has 0 width in the designer. When I deploy the application to my device the control renders as expected. Is there any way to fix this?

For reference, I'm trying to build a simple toolbar that has a bunch of clickable icons. I'm sure there are other ways of achieving this but I'm using this as a learning as my XAML skills are pretty lacking. My code can be found below.

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <local:ActionIcon  IconData="{StaticResource Test}" ></local:ActionIcon>
</StackPanel>
```

**ActionIcon.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Name="userControl"
    x:Class="UwpTest.ActionIcon"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:UwpTest"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="200"
    d:DesignWidth="200">
    <Viewbox Stretch="UniformToFill">
        <Path Stretch="UniformToFill" 
              Data="{Binding IconData, ElementName=userControl}" 
              Fill="Black" />
    </Viewbox>
</UserControl>
```

**ActionIcon.xaml.cs**

```
public sealed partial class ActionIcon : UserControl
    {
        public ActionIcon()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string IconData
        {
            get
            {
                return (string) GetValue(IconDataProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(IconDataProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IconDataProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "IconData", typeof(string), typeof(ActionIcon), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));
    }
```

**ResourceDictionary Entry**

```
<x:String x:Key="Test">M10,16.5V7.5L16,12M12,2A10,10 0 0,0 2,12A10,10 0 0,0 12,22A10,10 0 0,0 22,12A10,10 0 0,0 12,2Z</x:String>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nutshell, the problem is that the types of IconData and Path.Data don't match. While IconData is a string, Path.Data wants a Geometry. So if you want to put the path's data in a resource dictionary, its type has to be Geometry or one of its subclasses. Consider, that WPF won't throw an exception when a binding fails. Instead you get a message in the Output-Window of Visual Studio.

**But why can I use a string when I set the Path.Data-Property directly?**

The Path never really gets a string. When the XAML parser gets a wrong type for a property, it looks at the class of the type it expected. It's searching there for a TypeConversion-Attribute. When the parser looks at Geometry, it finds such an attribute:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(GeometryConverter))]
abstract partial class Geometry
```

The attribute specifies a TypeConverter. For Geometry it is GeomtryConverter, which can convert strings to Geometry. There's an article at msdn about that, if you want to know more: [How to: Implement a Type Converter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx)

**Fine, but how do I use Geomtries in ResourceDictionaries?**

The thing becomes clear once you try to create an path without asiging a string to Path.Data. A simple bezier curve before:

```
<Path Data="M 10,100 C 10,300 300,-200 300,100" />
```

and after:

```
<Path>
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathFigure StartPoint="10,100">
                    <BezierSegment Point1="10,300" Point2="300,-200" Point3="300,100"/>
                </PathFigure>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
```

The TypeConverter produces such an output. Only the points are again converted by a TypeConverter. However, the next step is simple: Just put the PathGeometry in the ResourceDictionary.

As a little side node: You can avoid using ElementName for every binding by setting the user controls DataContext to itself:

```
<UserControl DataContext={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
```